# NVL function in oracle can be filter with the other condition?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a SQL scipt, I used the function NVL with condition "not null".
Can it check, row by row, which row is not null and which one is null?

```
select * from table where nvl(Column A,column B) is not null
```

Because maybe the column A is null and column not null.

Comment: Select * from table where nvl(Column A,column B) is not null

Comment: OK, that's correct as far as syntax is concerned. But, what is the question/problem?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve all rows from `table` where either `Column A` is not null or `Column B` is not null?

Comment: current Column A is not have data, and column B have data, but in future the column A is have data.
so problem here some row will have column A data and some row is not.
so i still want to show it all 
if column A not have data it can be replace by the column B

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve])

Comment: I'm lost on what you want to do.  For instance `NVL()` doesn't check *rows*, it checks values in *columns*.

Answer (score 0):

To select A or B

```
select 
    case when A is not null then A else B end as AorB,
    ...
from table
```

Note that AorB returns null if both A and B are null. If you want to filter such records out:

```
select ...
from
(
    select 
        case when A is not null then A else B end as AorB,
        ...
    from table
)
where AorB is not null;
```